# Route not being entered/hit

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following `server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8080;

app.get('js/', function (req, res) {
    var uid = req.params.uid,
        file = req.originalUrl.substring(1) ? req.originalUrl.substring(1) : 'index.html';

    console.log("RULE: 'js/'");

    //res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/js");
    res.sendfile(file, {
        //root: './bower_components/common-static-content/src/main/webapp/js/theaa/components/'
        root: './src/main/webapp/'
    });
});

app.get('', function (req, res) {
    var uid = req.params.uid,
        file = req.originalUrl.substring(1) ? req.originalUrl.substring(1) : 'index.html';

    console.log("RULE: ''");

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.sendfile(file, {
        root: './src/main/webapp/'
    });
});

var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

however, the second rule seems to be being hit correctly (ie when the URL doesn't start with `localhost:8080/js/`) but at the same time, I am not getting any console output when I got to `http://localhost:8080/js/ngDate.js`

This is the first time I have used Node/Express so I am a n00b, can someone please point out, what it is I am doing wrong please?

Cheers!

Comment: why don't you say `/` and `/js`.

Comment: because I want a one rule hits them all to save time, and there could/will be file in sub dirs too.....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, because the `js/` **only** matches `js/` - not more and not less.

Maybe you want to have a look at `express.static()` to serve static files like Javascript and CSS.